# Userdir with Virtual Host (Apache2)

Tags: 16.04, apache2, virtualhost

Using Ubuntu 16.04 and Apache 2.4.7
I want to make two different types of userdir.

1. The data is in `/home/user/public_html/` and accessed only via www.sample.com/~user/. (www2.sample.com/~user/ should not work.)
2. The data is in `/home/user/public_html2/` and accessed only via www2.sample.com/~user/. (www.sample.com/~user/ should not work.)

I finished making the two virtual hosts using /etc/apache2/sites-availabile/000-default.conf, and then tried to modify mods-available/userdir.conf. It was easy to make either public_html or public_html2 accessible, but failed to make both accessible with different host names. Could you teach me how to do this?

I cannot write code as it is, but 000-default.conf and userdir.conf are like these:

000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@sample.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/www
    ServerName www.sample.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</irtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@sample.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/www2
    ServerName www2.sample.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</irtualHost>
```

userdir.conf (The first half of this code is the original userdir.conf. I simply copied and pasted below the original one, and changed public_html to public_html2.)

```
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    UserDir public_html
    UserDir disabled root
    <Directory /home/*/public_html>
        AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit Indexes
        Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec
        <Limit GET POST OPTIONS>
            Require all granted
        </Limit>
        <LimitExcept GET POST OPTIONS>
            Require all denied
        </LimitExcept>
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    UserDir public_html2
    UserDir disabled root
    <Directory /home/*/public_html2>
        AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit Indexes
        Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec
        <Limit GET POST OPTIONS>
            Require all granted
        </Limit>
        <LimitExcept GET POST OPTIONS>
            Require all denied
        </LimitExcept>
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Can you edit into your question the content of `000-default.conf` and `mods-available/userdir.conf`?

Comment: @Dan I added the program. Hope you find a solution. Thanks.

Comment: I edited my answer to use your config, mine had a simple a minimal config to make this work. The extra configs you have grant a little more security for your hosting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I 100% understand your question, but I assume you are asking to have 2 different domains where each one of them uses a different UserDir.

**EDIT**: You were on the right track. The only thing you had missing, is that you needed to put each of the two UserDir configs in their respective VirtualHost config as seen below.

For that, you need to create two virtual hosts, and each Virtual host would have its own UserDir configurations.

The first virtual host would contain the following:

```
# /etc/apache2/sites-available/com.sample.www.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.sample.com

    <IfModule mod_userdir.c>
        UserDir public_html
        UserDir disabled root
        <Directory /home/*/public_html>
            AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit Indexes
            Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec
            <Limit GET POST OPTIONS>
                Require all granted
            </Limit>
            <LimitExcept GET POST OPTIONS>
                Require all denied
            </LimitExcept>
        </Directory>
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

The second virtual host would contain the following:

```
# /etc/apache2/sites-available/com.sample.www2.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www2.sample.com
    UserDir public_html2

    <IfModule mod_userdir.c>
        UserDir disabled root
        <Directory /home/*/public_html2>
            AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit Indexes
            Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec
            <Limit GET POST OPTIONS>
                Require all granted
            </Limit>
            <LimitExcept GET POST OPTIONS>
                Require all denied
            </LimitExcept>
        </Directory>
     </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

Once that is done, you need to enable the 2 virtual host config files and restart Apache.

```
$ sude a2dissite 000-default.conf
$ sudo a2ensite com.sample.www.conf
$ sudo a2ensite com.sample.www2.conf
$ sudo apache2ctl restart
```

Now, when you open `www.sample.com/~dan/` it will use `/home/dan/public_html/`
and when you open `www2.sample.com/~dan/` it will use `/home/dan/public_html2/`

Comment: I did `sudo a2dissite 000-default` and `sudo a2dismod userdir`. Then created com.sample.www.conf and `sudo a2ensite com.sample.www`. (Haven't made www2 version yet.) However, www.sample.com/~user/ does not even work... The browser says forbidden...

Comment: `userdir` should still be enabled, you should not disable it. The config I have is still taking leverage of the userdir module.

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciated. The website seems to be working, but I have two more questions. Currently my `userdir.conf` has code only about public_html (the latter half was deleted), but public_html2 is also working. Why does this happen? If you know how to make basic authentication available only in public_html2, could you tell me the way?

Comment: In that case `UserDir public_html` will be the considered the default, and the config `UserDir public_html2` in com.sample.www2.conf will overwrite that value just for `www2.sample.com`. So if you create a new VirtualHost later without any UserDir config, it will use the `public_html` directory. I would recommend you remove it but leave the `UserDir disabled root` line for security purposes.

Comment: As for the basic auth, whatever configuration you add in the `com.sample.www2.conf` file (Between the `<VirtualHost *:80>` and `</VirtualHost>` tags), will be only valid for `www2.sample.com` (i.e. `public_html2)`. So you just need to add the appropriate Basic Auth configuration in its respective virtual host. If you still need help with setting that up, I'd recommend asking a new question about it (Although I'd assume there may already be one) so this question and answer don't become too broad.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying multisite on one hostname you may use userdir module. You can access by user home directory with /~username with browser. In your code in bottom * adresses public_html folder under user's home directory. So no need to add second and more Directory tags in userdir.conf. Details: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_userdir.html

```
...
<Directory /home/*/public_html>
      AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit Indexes
      Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec
      <Limit GET POST OPTIONS>
         Require all granted
      </Limit>
      <LimitExcept GET POST OPTIONS>
         Require all denied
      </LimitExcept>
</Directory>
...
```